# Check if string variable is null or empty, or full of white spaces

Tags: string, twig, isnullorempty

How can I check if a string variable is null or empty, or full with space characters in Twig? (Shortest possible, maybe an equivalent to CSharp's `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method)

Comment: Sorry to all, I reverted the question to the original statement, as the answer was chosen based on it. I modified it in a not so lucid moment of mine to look like a very similar but not exactly the same question.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are already good answers, but I give my 2 cents too:

```
{% if foo|length %}
```

I was inspired by @GuillermoGutiérrez's filter trick.

But I think `|length` is safer as the `"0"|trim` expression will evaluates to false.

References :

- [length](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html)
- [codepad](http://codepad.org/XrjyBSCT)
- [boolval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.boolval.php)

Comment: too much of a hack, imho

Comment: @alanTiemblo - the most voted answer, I'd say. Still imho :-)

Answer (score 74):

```php
{% if your_variable is null or your_variable is empty %}
```

should check whether the variable is null or empty.

If you want to see if it's **not** null or empty just use the `not`operator.

```php
{% if foo is not null and foo is not empty %}
```

See the docs:

- [empty](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tests/empty.html)
- [null](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tests/null.html)
- ["is" operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#test-operator)
- [logical operators like "not"](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#logic)

Perhaps you might be interested in [tests in twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tests/index.html) generally.

Comment: I'm not `twig` specialist, but shouldn't it be `{% if foo is not null ` **and** `foo is not empty %}`? Otherwise seems like it will be always true.

Comment: @SirDerpington is the `foo is (not) null` part still necessary? Twig documentation states that `empty` also checks if the value equals `null`

Comment: @sschwei1 that's a good catch. According to the documentation that's indeed true. Not sure how it was back in 2014 though

Answer (score 20):

I'd rather use just **[trim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/trim.html)** and **[empty](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/empty.html)**:

```php
{% if foo|trim is empty %} 

{% if foo|trim is not empty %}
```

***empty*** evaluates to true if the *foo* variable is:

- null
- false
- empty array
- empty string

Answer (score 7):

`{% if foo|trim %}` seems to be enough (assuming that `foo` is the variable to check). If `foo` is not null, `trim` removes whitespaces. Also, `if` handles empty string or null as false, and true otherwise, so no more is required.

References:

- [trim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/trim.html)

Comment: Unless foo contains stuff like the number 0 or the string "0".